# Header location no funciona al ejecutar una funcion com jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Estoy  haciendo una pagina y al enviar el formulario deveria abrir otra pagina.
Mi problemas es que este formulario esta em un modal y quando se ejecuta com una función de jquery, donde deveria abrir solo um mensage se hay algun problema, tambien me muestra todo el contenido de la otra pagina. Como puedo resolver este problema, desde ya muchas gracias a quien pueda ayudarme.

para que lo entienda mejor dejo el print aqui

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi código para llamar el mensage despues de ejecutar el formulario

```
function mapabordo(){
 $("#btn_mapabordo").click(function () {

                //Receber os dados do formulário
                var dados = $("#mapabordoform_dash").serialize();

                $.post("mapabordo.php", dados, function (retorna) {
                  $("#msgmapabordo").slideDown('slow').html(retorna);


               });

            });

     };
```

Y este es el código para direcionar para otra pagina.

```
    if($seatPassageiro !==''){
             $sql= " UPDATE  cliente2 SET seatPassageiro= '$seatPassageiro', contrato = '$contrato' WHERE id_cliente2= '$id_cliente2' and seatPassageiro = '' ";



            $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

            if($resultado){
                header("Location: contrato_pdf.php?excurssao=".$id_escurcao."&passageiro=".$id_cliente."");

            }else{
             echo '<p style="color:red; text-align:right;">Erro ao salvar dados.</p>' . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno he resulto el problema com window.location, aqui os dejo el código utilizado.

```
if($seatPassageiro !==''){
             $sql= " UPDATE  cliente2 SET seatPassageiro= '$seatPassageiro', contrato = '$contrato' WHERE id_cliente2= '$id_cliente2' and seatPassageiro = '' ";



            $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

            if($resultado){
                //header("Location: contrato_pdf.php?excurssao=".$id_escurcao."&passageiro=".$id_cliente."");
                echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.location.href =(\"contrato_pdf.php?excurssao=".$id_escurcao."&passageiro=".$id_cliente."\");</script>";

            }else{
             echo '<p style="color:red; text-align:right;">Erro ao salvar dados.</p>' . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
            }
        }
```